# Change td class dynamically with Datatables

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, datatables

so I'm trying to change the td class of my datatables elements dynamically. From my research i found fnRowCallback, it seems to be the solution but I can't get it to work. From 1 of the questions here at Stack I found:

```
 "fnRowCallback": function( nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex, iDisplayIndexFull ) {
    for (var i in aData)  {

      // Check if a cell contains data in the following format:
      // '[state] content'
      if (aData[i].substring(0,1)=='[') {

        // remove the state part from the content and use the given state as CSS class
        var stateName= aData[i].substring(1,aData[i].indexOf(']'));
        var content= aData[i].substring(aData[i].indexOf(']')+1);
        $('td:eq('+i+')', nRow).html(content).addClass(stateName);
      }
    }
  }
```

But this does not work for me, I get the error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token, and my elements keep the "[class name] content" format. Here is my javascript function:

```
$('#tableId').DataTable({
     "ajax" :  "function.php",

     "columns" : [ 
     {
      "data" : "id"
 }, {
      "data" : "firstElement"
 }, {
      "data" : "secondElement"
 }, {
      "data" : "thirdElement" 
 }],

 "fnRowCallback": function( nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex, iDisplayIndexFull ) {
    for (var i in aData)  {

      // Check if a cell contains data in the following format:
      // '[state] content'
      if (aData[i].substring(0,1)=='[') {

        // remove the state part from the content and use the given state as CSS class
        var stateName= aData[i].substring(1,aData[i].indexOf(']'));
        var content= aData[i].substring(aData[i].indexOf(']')+1);
        $('td:eq('+i+')', nRow).html(content).addClass(stateName);
      }
    }
  },

 "iDisplayLength": 5,

 "scrollX": true,

 "orderFixed": [[ 0, "asc"]]

});
```

function.php gives me a JSON with all the fields, and in the ones I want the class altered I use "[class name] content" in the field. Any ideas on how to get it to work?

Thanks

Comment: By "Unexpected token", I guess there is some typo. It would help us to solve fast if you can setup JsFiddle or runnable code here.

Comment: This error was appearing only when I tried to run the function in the console. But in the code it is working, I tested with console.log. What is not working is the line $('td:eq('+i+')', nRow).html(content).addClass(stateName);

Comment: May be unprintable character in code causing issue. Just remove blank lines before and after and try it.

Answer (score 0):

Problem with your code is that `aData` would be an associative array, for example:

```
{ "id": 1, "firstElement": "[class] content" }
```

When you enumerate properties with `for...in` construct, `i` would hold property name (`id`, `firstElement`) and not numerical index.

Therefore you cannot use `i` to access cell within given row.

Another problem with your code is that it sets HTML content after it has been created. jQuery DataTables will be unaware that you've updated cell content.